# ipad cordova whitelist rejection

Tags: ios, cordova

I try to access local url, expose the application by `IIS` (`http://<localip>:<port>`), I can access it with the iPad browser.

The mobile application use the WebViewer to show the url.

The first problem was the "Transport Security policy" related with the https (the local site is not exposed through SSL), but I can resolve adding the following line in the config.xml

```
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="">
   <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</config-file>
```

The second problem is the whitelist, it block the access to local url.
I have added the plugin `cordova-plugin-whitelist`

In the config.xml I added

```
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="">
    <key>ExternalHosts</key>
    <array>
        <string>*</string>
    </array>
</config-file>
```

and

```
<preference name="OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" value="true" />
```

but with it doesn't work

In the config.xml also has the lines

```
<access origin="*"/>  
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
```

but I think that it is related with android

Also I try with

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

in the index.html, but not work

Someone knows what else can I try?